# Mybatis foreach of HashMap<String, Object[]>

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

So I am trying to dynamically generate the WHERE clause of a SQL statement via Mybatis. I have a HashMap where the key is the column name, and the value is an Object[] with the following format: { operator, value1, value2 }. I have the following in my Mybatis Mapper:

```
WHERE 
    <foreach item="colArgs" index="colName" collection="whereMap.entrySet()"  open="(" separator=" AND " close=")">
        <bind name="operator" value="colArgs[0]" />
        <bind name="value1" value="colArgs[1]" />
        <bind name="value2" value="colArgs[2]" />
        <if test="colArgs[0] == ' BETWEEN ' ">
            ${colName} ${operator} #{value1} AND #{value2}
        </if>
        <if test="colArgs[0] != ' BETWEEN ' ">
            ${colName} ${operator} #{value1}
        </if>
    </foreach>
```

When I pass in the following HashMap:

```
{"colName1", {" = ", "foo", ""}}, {"colName2", {" BETWEEN ", 1, 2}}
```

I expect:

```
WHERE (colName1 = "foo") AND (colName2 BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
```

However MyBatis interprets it as the following:

```
WHERE (colName1 = 1) AND (colName2 BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
```

Even if I remove the  and use #{colArgs[1]} directly, the same issue persists. Interestingly, ${operator}/${colArgs[0]} works as expected. Unfortunately, using $ instead of # is not an option as that causes type mismatches with columns of different types (exception: `Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer`).

I am relatively new to MyBatis, especially the Dynamic SQL stuff so any help in identifying what I did wrong will be appreciated.

Comment: The piece of code you've pasted is not a real piece of code, it has syntax error (missing quote near `close=")`). Otherwise it works as intended for me with mybatis 3.4.6. Are you sure you pass the correct `whereMap`?

Comment: Sorry, I was editing the XML to make it more readable for this question so that was a typo on my part. I have confirmed in Java/Spring that the whereMap is correct when it is passed into the mapper.
Additionally, if I use `${colArgs[1]}` instead of `#{colArgs[1]}` the value substituted is correct, but causes issues in the case of `{"varcharColumn", {" = ", "1", ""}}` generating `(varcharColumn = 1)` where 1 is interpreted by PSQL as an integer. Do I really have to change my `whereMap` to put string values in SQL varchar form? I am using myBatis 3.3.0 if that helps.